# how to ensure that our site authenticates with kerberos

Tags: httpwebrequest, impersonation, kerberos, delegation, unauthorized

I am working with HttpWebRequest in dotnet. I am using delegation (impersonation) to do this,
 request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.ImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

in webconfig file

identity impersonate="true"

for Impersonation Kerberos is required...
So i need to ensure wether the site authenticates using kerberos or NTLM
because my code throws 401 unauthorized error

so please help me in this!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the account you are impersonating trusted for delegation in the AD?

Comment: yes only for my server i have configured to support delegation